# Executar uma migration passando parametros no Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, migrations

Estou criando uma aplicação robusta onde vou definir qual será os comandos a serem executados dentro de uma base de dados conforme o subdomínio (que também é o nome da base de dados do cliente). Como posso passar esse parâmetro para uma migration do Laravel? Procuro algo assim:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDb extends Migration{

    public function up($dbname){
        DB::select( DB::raw( 'CREATE DATABASE :db', ['db'=>$dbname] ) );
    }

    public function down($dbname){
        DB::select( DB::raw( 'DROP DATABASE :db', ['db'=>$dbname] ) );
    }

}
```